# Javascript insertBefore method cannot be called mulitple times adding same child node?

Tags: javascript

I tried to add same element to the HTML document multiple times, but it doesn't work, I don't know the reason. The code is following:

```
<html>
<body>

<div>Very</div>
<div>Secret</div>
<script>
  var elem = document.createElement('div')
  elem.innerHTML = '**Child**'

  document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.lastChild);
  document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.lastChild);
  document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.lastChild);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

why the result is

```
  Very
  Secret
**Child**
```

instead of

```
  Very
  Secret
**Child**
**Child**
**Child**
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DOM manipulation methods like [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) move elements if they are already in DOM tree. That's why you end up with only one node appended to the end.

If you want to create three *different* nodes, then you have a couple of options.

**1). Cloning node**. Using [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) you can append cloned node instead of original:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div')
elem.innerHTML = '**Child**';

document.body.insertBefore(elem.cloneNode(true), document.body.lastChild);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xh3nqe85/

**2). String as template**. You can append HTML string instead of NodeElement. The most convenient method for this manipulation is [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML):

```
var elem = '<div>**Child**</div>';
document.body.lastElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', elem);
document.body.lastElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', elem);
document.body.lastElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', elem);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xh3nqe85/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should create the element for three times.

In the way you did you are just creating one element and setting it three times:

```
    function myFun() {
        var elem = document.createElement('div')
        elem.innerHTML = '**Child**'
        return elem;
    }
    document.body.insertBefore(myFun(), document.body.lastChild);
    document.body.insertBefore(myFun(), document.body.lastChild);
    document.body.insertBefore(myFun(), document.body.lastChild);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zppunvv/

Answer (score 1):

When you append a node to a different node, you aren't cloning it.

See the **[`Node.cloneNode`](http://devdocs.io/dom/node.clonenode)** method to actually clone a node.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clone the node.

```
var elem = document.createElement('div')
elem.innerHTML = '**Child**'

document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.lastChild);
document.body.insertBefore(elem.cloneNode(true),document.body.lastChild);
document.body.insertBefore(elem.cloneNode(true),document.body.lastChild);
```